# MSSQL Using Job @powershell running stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

can i have steps based answer to my query

we want to run stored procedure as **job** on regular interval using power shell style formatting output to file.

Procedure contents:
simple select query

Some checking did:
when we are calling procedure using invoke-sqlcmd -q "exec xxx" it work perfect from power shell
Stuck at:
need to know how to call from job section using power shell to run like invoking from power shell

Comment: SQL Agent does have PowerShell job steps, so have you tried launching a PowerShell script that invokes the stored procedure and writes the results in the desired format?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/run-windows-powershell-steps-in-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: i was trying but syntax was different when you copy past running command from powershell then open import to job step. last it worked by  saving same command @txt file and importing it at job step.